# xcodebuild (XCode 7.1) - unexpected successful exit code from cancelled command

Tags: xcode, xcodebuild

I'm getting the following during the bundle resources copying phase in xcodebuild (XCode 7.1):

> 2015-11-03 22:16:28.218 xcodebuild[28202:300463]  DVTAssertions:
>   Warning in
>   /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/IDEXcode3ProjectSupport/IDEXcode3ProjectSupport-9061/Xcode3Core/LegacyProjects/Frameworks/DevToolsCore/DevToolsCore/BuildSystem/Runtime/PBXTargetBuildContext.mm:739
>   Details:  **unexpected successful exit code from cancelled command**
>   `<C0505:'CpResource Foo.json':P10>` Object:   `<PBXTargetBuildContext:
>   0x7faec015a440>` Method:
>   `-createCommandInvocationRecordFromInvocation:` Thread:   `<NSThread: 0x7faebc8cc070>`{number = 10, name = (null)} Please file a bug at
>   http://bugreport.apple.com with this warning message and any useful
>   information you can provide.

I have ~170 items I'm copying, but for some reason a few of them give me this error.

**EDIT** - I just ran the command again and now it works, so it doesn't seem deterministic.

Comment: Asked in apple's forums too: https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/84183#84183

Comment: so after you reran it and it worked you set a bounty on your question?

Comment: @marczking it worked a couple of times and then stopped working. I'm now considering copying the bundle resources myself as a shell script phase.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue was a duplicate folder in the *Copy Bundle Resources* section. It used to be two different files, but they were moved so XCode decided to change them both to the folder they got moved into. Go figure.

Answer (score 0):

Had this issue a couple of months ago. Today that error made it's comback.
I have it only if I try to emulate from ionic (--livereload)  on a iOS-Device. Seem like if you have Xcode running it occurs. Close Xcode. That fixes it.